# MATLAB: Generate sample from a known density function

Tags: matlab, distribution

I want to write a function that generates samples from a distribution. To do that, I know its continuous density function. The first idea that came into mind was to write a code like this one:

```
% a and b are know coefficients.
% besselj is a MATLAB function.

x = 0:0.0001:5;
% PDF=density function (PDF=a (1 x 50.000) vector)
PDF = (x/b).*exp(-(x.^2+a^2)./(2*b)).*besselj(1,(x.*a)./b);
% density function has to be normalized
PDF = PDF./sum(PDF)

% y=the vector containing the sample
[temp , y] = histc(rand(1 , N), [0 cumsum(PDF)]);
```

For the curious ones, this density function represents a Rice distribution ;-).

However, on second thoughts, this algorithm seems bad. Indeed, from a 100%-known density function, I get a partially-known discretized density function (the vector PDF) and I rely on this new density function to obtain samples. I think that some information is lost because of the discretization.

So, **my question is the following**: *Is there a way I can generate sample from a continuous density function without loosing information* ?

Moreover, the code above doesn't seem good to me because the magnitudes of the plot(x,PDF) before and after the normalization are absolutely not the same.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling

Comment: If it's a Rice distribution: you only need to generate a normalized complex Gaussian variable, sum a constant (related to the Rice factor), and take the absolute value. Do a Google search for details, but it's as simple as that

Comment: Thanks bdecaf, your link seems to be very interesting !